# use helper of handlebars-express in view

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am using nodejs as a backend and the handlebars-express library

I have 3 files, my index.js, loginController.js and loginTemplate.handlebars

In my index.js I have declared handlebars like this

```
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
const server = express();

var hbs = handlebars.create({
  helpers: {
    getStringifiedJson: function (value) {
      return JSON.stringify(value);
    },
    ifCond: function (v1, operator, v2, options) {
      switch (operator) {
        case '==':
          return v1 == v2 ? true : false;
        case '===':
          return v1 === v2 ? true : false;
        case '!=':
          return v1 != v2 ? true : false;
        case '!==':
          return v1 !== v2 ? true : false;
        case '<':
          return v1 < v2 ? true : false;
        case '<=':
          return v1 <= v2 ? true : false;
        case '>':
          return v1 > v2 ? true : false;
        case '>=':
          return v1 >= v2 ? true : false;
        case '&&':
          return v1 && v2 ? true : false;
        case '||':
          return v1 || v2 ? true : false;
        default:
          return false;
      }
    },
  },
  layoutsDir: __dirname + '/src/views',
});

server.set('view engine', hbs);
```

In my loginController I have this

```
const { getTemplate } = require('../services/handlebarsService');

    getTemplate('loginController/loginTemplate', data).then(
      (loginCompiledTemplate) => {
        res.send(loginCompiledTemplate);
      }
    );
```

My handlebars service:

```
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create();

const getTemplate = async (path, data) => {
  const template = await handlebars
    .getTemplate(`./src/views/${path}.handlebars`)
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  return template(data);
};

module.exports = { getTemplate };
```

But when in my view I try to call "ifCond" it doesn't recognize it, because it gives me this error

```
{{#if campos }}
{{#each camposManuales}}
{{#ifCond this.field_type == 1 }}
  a
{{/ifCond}}
{{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

The error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Parse error on line 14:
           .field_type == 1 }}
```

How can i fix this? What is wrong? Thank u so much!! ^^

Comment: The `.create()` function creates new instance of handlebars engine so you need to pass the same options(helpers, layoutsDir) to it as you did in the index.js. My question is why don't you use `res.render()` instead of your `handlebarsService`? If all you do in the `handlebarsService` is what you are showing in your question, then you don't need it at all, just use `res.render();`

Comment: hello @Molda thanks for commenting. Everything I show in the service is what it contains, it is correct. How could I pass it by res.render? can you send me an example? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use your `handlebarsService` since you can use `res.render` function as shown bellow. The `render` function internaly does essentialy the same you do in the `handlebarsService`.

```
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
const server = express();

var hbs = handlebars.create({
    helpers: {
        toJson: ...,
        ifCond: ...
    }
});


app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', './views');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // there must be a home.html file in ./views folder
    res.render('home' /*, { some: 'data' }*/);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**Note:**
The `create` function makes a new instance of handlebars so in order for your code to work, you would have to pass same options(helpers, etc.) to both instances.

Comment: And how can I render the rest of the 'views' of my other controllers?

Comment: Like this `res.render('loginController/loginTemplate')` if that's what you mean.

Comment: without instace another Handlebars?

Comment: Yes one instance can handle it all.